# convert an MSAccess DataBase to an SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access-2010

I want to know if there is a way to convert an MSAccess DataBase to a SQL Server database without starting from the beginning.

Comment: You must always begin at the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

There's a pretty verbose guide over at Microsoft that helps you get this process started. This is specifically for SQL Server 2008 though, using the SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) which replaced the Upsizing Wizard: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/migration.aspx

Download: [SQL Server Migration Assistant 2008 for Access V4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=133b59c2-c89c-4641-bebb-6d04476ec1ba&DisplayLang=en)
Note: *"SSMA for Access supports Access 97 - Access 2007 databases."*

Comment: Note that the first link now redirects to a sales page for SQL-Server 2016.